# Check if console supports ANSI escape codes in Java

Tags: java, ansi-escape

I'm building a program in Java that uses menus with different colors using ANSI escape codes. Something like

```
System.out.println("\u001B[36m"+"Menu option"+"\u001B[0m");
```

The problem is that i want to check if the console where the code is going to be executed supports using this codes, so in case it doesn't, print an alternative version without the codes.

It will be something similar to:

```
if(console.supportsANSICode){
   System.out.println("\u001B[36m"+"Menu option"+"\u001B[0m");
}
else{
   System.out.println("Menu option");
}
```

Is there a method in java to check this?

Comment: The point is, checking if the console supports the ANSI escape codes isn't the best way to do this. In fact, you have to use a `PrintWriter`, on the `System.out` writer so you can set the Encoding type on it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple java-only solution:

```
if (System.console() != null && System.getenv().get("TERM") != null) {
    System.out.println("\u001B[36m"+"Menu option"+"\u001B[0m");
} else {
    System.out.println("Menu option");
}
```

The first term is there to check if a terminal is attached, second to see if TERM env var is defined (is not on Windows). This isn't perfect, but works well enough in my case.

Comment: I tested it and as you have said, doesn't work on Windows, but is useful for Unix systems.
Since it has been 2 years, i will mark this as an answer.

Comment: @slye you may also try something like https://github.com/fusesource/jansi but requires a native library on windows

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if Java has some special way to deal with this, but there are two ways to deal with the problem itself. The usual method used (at least in the unix world) is to get the terminal used from the `TERM` environment variable and look up it's capabilities from the [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo)/[termcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) database (usually using [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) or [slang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Lang_(programming_library))). Another more crude approach is to send the Device Status Report code (`"\u001B[6n"`) and check if the terminal responds. This is of course a bit of a hack since a terminal that supports the DSR code might not support color for example.