# How to test if console supports ANSI color codes?

Tags: c++, windows, terminal, ansi-colors, fmt

I use fmt based logger with optionally color prints - which relies on ANSI color commands.

Unfortunately on Windows 10 it is disabled by default. I know how to enable it but I still want to find out how to test whether the console supports ANSI commands or not. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows you can get/set the ANSI color support by checking/setting the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` flag with [`SetConsoleMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) or [`GetConsoleMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolemode).

There's also the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\VirtualTerminalLevel` registry key for [global virtual terminal settings](https://superuser.com/a/1300251/241386). See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences

On *nix you can use the following ways

- [Check if console supports ANSI escape codes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41057014/995714)
- [Programmatically detect the ANSI escape code supported by terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159718/44425)